# How to open an activity that belong to another app?

Tags: android

helle everyone ,

I have two application that work fine , I have ApplicationA imported in android studio and I want to import ApplicationB (which have its own manifest and buil.gradle files) in the same project , and then open an ApplicationB activity (that uses resourses from ApplicationB) from ApplicationA ?

Answer (score 0):

Do as below:

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(MY_PACKAGE_NAME);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: but how I import the ApplicationB first ??

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer - 
Call another app activity like below -

```
Intent inent = new Intent("com.example.android.another.app.ANOTHER_ACTIVITY");
startActivity(inent);
```

Your calling activity's manifest code will be like below -

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.android.another.app.AnotherActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.android.another.app.ANOTHER_ACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: do I import the AplicationB as an application or library  ??

Comment: No you don't need to do that.

Comment: thanks bro but I think u didnt understand my question ,I need both the ApplicationA and ApplicationB to be in the same apk in the end

Comment: Are you trying to create module or library?

Comment: I tried to use library but didnt work , as I said I have two android studio projects (two apps : appA andapp B) and when I click a button for exemple from appA I want appB to be executed ,now the question is how I will import appB into my main project which is appA

Comment: You can make any of the project as module or .aar file or library or sdk0. And then just add that module/library/.aar file to your project by linking in your main project. 

Here is the url - how can you develop a module. 
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library